# What's the largest number you can spell?

Tags: mathematics

If I give you one of each letter in the alphabet what's the largest you can spell (in word form)?

**Bonus: What's the smallest?**

**Bonus 2: What if you can use the words "minus", "plus" and "times"?**

Comment: As for bonus: do you need to use letters for 'negative'?
If so 'negative four' is the first contender I can come up with for bonus 1.

Comment: @TimCouwelier The word 'n[e]gativ[e]' itself cannot be formed with just one alphabet, so I'm afraid that won't fly.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable.  Various people have invented competing or mutually exclusive large number systems with various levels of acceptance.

Comment: The question is answerable with the (entirely reasonable) assumption that this is about American or British decimal number systems and using only English letters.

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop Language, locale, and letters are a different issue.  Please view: http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_googologisms

Comment: @Muqo a very large portion of those are exactly what I'm intending to exclude. Numbers like "a dozen" or "eleventy" might have accepted meanings, but those are just special names given to special numbers. It **should** be pretty clear which numbers are included. However, the overloadedness of, say, "million" does cause a problem. in any case, the answer should be clarified.

Comment: @Time use "minus"

Comment: @warspyking calm down about everyone using loopholes. That's the fun of it.

Comment: I understand that you would want an answer that interprets the question as you see it (since it is your puzzle). You're free to accept whichever answer you agree with (or were expecting). I'm just pointing out that some people like thinking outside the box and finding interesting answers (which we know are loopholes) so you didn't have to comment that on every answer.

Comment: @Bobo I know, I'm just going wait for a response to my meta post.

Comment: I really want to find a way to say "the least number that cannot be expressed using at most one of each letter of the alphabet" using at most one of each letter of the alphabet. This number necessarily is larger than any correct answer, but if we can express it within the rules then it's also a correct answer, hence contradiction. But I haven't got any such expression yet.

Comment: You did not precisely define the question *in the question*. It is nonsense to then claim that answers are cheating/loopholes when they meet the little criteria you specified, but weren't quite what you had in mind. (you might redefine the question to exclude certain types of answers, but do so in the question for all to see, and know that means you might tick off the earlier answerers)

Comment: Related to the unrestricted form of the question: [Profs Duke It Out in Big Number Duel](http://tech.mit.edu/V126/N64/64largenumber.html) Two Philosophers Vie to Write Largest Possible Finite Number on Chalkboard.  Another account of the duel (with winning entry) can be found at [Big Number Duel](http://web.mit.edu/arayo/www/bignums.html).  Links are fun to chase from there.

Comment: Oh the irony. The one trying to score 'points' by giving attempted witty or 'out of the box' answers, is annoyed by people trying to do it on his own question.

Comment: Wish I could answer. `c squared`, which comes out to be about 8.98755179 × 10^16, is the best I could do.

Comment: thousand! (i is upside down, and becomes the factorial symbol).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a number immensely bigger than $\omega$, consider the uncountably infinite number hidden below.   (Note, by the way, that $\omega$ is countably infinite, and rather than being the biggest something, it is in fact  “the smallest infinite ordinal ... as it is the least upper bound of the natural numbers” [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal#Examples)]).  So **omega** is a good candidate for the first bonus, the smallest number one can spell if given one of each letter in the alphabet.

Answer:

> The transfinite number **aleph sixtyfour** appears to be the biggest aleph ($\aleph$) number one can spell if given one of each letter in the alphabet.
>  Note that  $\aleph_{64} > \aleph_{63} > ... \aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0  = \omega$.
> (For a big number that doesn't quite work because it has two a's and e's, see wikipedia's [Aleph-ω](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number#Aleph-.CF.89) article; **aleph omega** is  the least upper bound of ${\aleph_n : n\in\{0,1,2,\dots}\}$.  But if we use five Roman and one Greek letter, or one Hebrew and one Greek letter, **aleph $\omega$** or **$\aleph_{\omega}$** work ok.)

Comment: I hid it for you.

Comment: But is it really a number or are we basically talking about a concept by that point? We could say then that 'inf' given by some calculators is the same thing, but it's not the answer of the calculator, simply the message that the number goes beyond the bounds of its memory.

Comment: @Volodya, a calculator's *inf* equals the smallest number mentioned above, $\omega$.  All the other numbers are bigger than that.

Comment: @jwpat7 You totally missed what i'm saying. It's not a number, it's a concept. You wouldn't accept 'NAN' (not a number) even if it didn't have two 'N'.

Comment: Not that it affects the answer, but the assertion $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ is the Continuum Hypothesis. It's independent of Zermelo-Fraenkel plus the Axiom of Choice, which is to say that it's basically up to the individual user whether to call it true or false.

Comment: How does "aleph omega" have two o's?

Comment: @Jasper, I’ve edited “two o’s” to “two a’s and e’s” in answer

Comment: @jwpat7: You're misunderstanding the usages of ordinal numbers. The "infinity" on a calculator is not *equal* to $\omega$, so far as they're not referring to the same concept in the same domain.

Comment: @jwpat7 Oh wow. I was trying so hard to see the second "o" that I didn't see either the second "e" or the "a"...

Comment: This answer contains two mathematical errors, one pointed out by @SteveJessop and the other in the notion that **omega** is the smallest number that etc. (it's certainly larger than, say, one). Moreover, it's independent of ZFC how aleph sixty-four compares with, say, [beth six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number).

Comment: Late to the party, but why stop at 64?  Why not aleph 9876543210?  Or aleph G (Graham's number)?

Answer (score 44):

> US Gov. Debt
>  17,907,911,809,200 at last glance. :P

Comment: Wow... This is a loop hole, but even so US translates to United States. 3 of the letter "t"and 2 of "e" and "s"

Comment: US is fine, why do you need to translate that to United States?

Comment: I've decided to go with the loop holes since there are so many of them, you win!

Comment: @warspyking, this answer is undeserving because he didn't fully spell out the word Government.  It is like saying inf. for infinity.

Comment: @Mew give it a few weeks, and US GOV DEBT will probably be higher than INF. anyway.

Comment: Made me curious and I found a clock [here](http://www.usdebtclock.org/) (and a minimal one [here](http://www.brillig.com/debt_clock/)).

Answer (score 25):

How about:

> *Megiston* aka. [*Megistron*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Megistron.html)

A decimal representation of this would require by far more digits than there are estimated atoms in the universe.

Comment: Clever but that's kinda looking for a loop hole. You have to spell it in word form, you wouldn't be able to use like "pi" because that means "three" then you've used 2 of the letter e so it don't count.

Comment: Hmm? Pi doesn't mean three.

Comment: I think this is a completely legit answer, the question didn't say you have to spell using only 0-9.

Comment: @Kevin That's as far as you can get though.

Comment: @warspyking Megistron is just as much a loophole as thousand.  It's the number's actual name.

Answer (score 24):

You did not specify which alphabet we should be using, so when using greek, the smallest would be

> ε

Comment: This is definitely a loophole, I mean seriously, the question was written in English.

Comment: Very clever trick. @warspyking: I changed ε to "epsilon", in order to use the Latin alphabet. How about now?

Comment: @Giulio I'm waiting for a response to a meta post..

Comment: Epsilon is used in English mathematics. It is a widely accepted.

Comment: It is widely accepted, yes, but not to refer to any specific number.

Answer (score 19):

There's also:

> [Oktria](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Oktria), which is between 3↑↑↑↑↑↑↑4 and 3↑↑↑↑↑↑↑5 in [Knuth's up arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Comment: Just like @GOTO 0 you're kinda looking for a loop hole.

Comment: How is this a loophole?

Answer (score 15):

For the first bonus question:

> Although there are lower numbers, none are *smaller* than **zero**.

Answer (score 12):

Taking the question literately, the best I can do is

> five thousand

Venturing outside the box, I can get to

> ULONG_MAX which (in the standard C library) comes out to (2^64)-1

Comment: Technically ULONG_MAX is another language.

Comment: Technically C doesn't specify which value is used for that var. On some systems this could be something different.

Comment: Nova is correct so perhaps instead of saying in C, say in the C standard library.

Comment: @warspyking I suppose, although it's only one step of translation from english, which is how most of these answers work.  Without the step of translation this question would be kind of boring.

Comment: @Nova Good point.  Corrected.

Comment: @MasterMastic: Isn't even the standard library of C implementation dependant?

Comment: @Nova Somewhat. I'll presume that ULONG_MAX really is in the spec (without verifying), so the size would really vary. For the most part `4294967295`, or `18446744073709551615`, which are still indeed quite big :P so it's valid on pretty much any common implementation.

Comment: Checking the most recent draft I see freely available online says yes.  It's on page 1238.  (Christ, that thing is long.) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf

Answer (score 12):

Just as a fun answer, for a loop hole:

> G 
>  This refers to Graham's number [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number), and is the largest number used in a serious mathematical proof. It is so large it is best expressed as a recurrence relation of Knuth's up-arrow notation as $G = g_{64}$ where $g_1 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$ and $g_n = 3\uparrow^{g_n-1}3$ (equations lifted shamelessly from Wikipedia). The phrase "many orders of magnitude" is negligible in the face of this number.

Comment: I thought about this number, too. Unfortunately it has multiple duplicates if you use more than just the first letter. In any case, this is definitely the biggest number mentioned so far.

Comment: Definitely just for fun answer, and yes, unfortunate that its full name has so many duplicates :/

Answer (score 10):

For bonus 1, if you use the convention that negative numbers are "minus x", then I think

> minus forty

wins. Checking everything down to minus one hundred is straightforward, and then anything less than minus one hundred must include either "hundred", "thousand", or one of the "-llion" words for higher powers of $10^3$ (or $10^6$, depending on convention, but it doesn't matter). And all of these contain an "n".

Comment: Negative two, although *lower* than minus one, is also *larger*.  You might have identified the *lowest* number that can be written each letter of the alphabet only once, but that doesn't mean it's the *smallest*.  Perhaps the question should be reworded, since there is no possible number smaller than the additive identity (zero), and it easily satisfies the conditions of the puzzle.

Comment: @supercat -2 is smaller than -1. I don't think your suggested difference between smaller and lower is actually recognised.

Comment: @JamesRyan: It's not unambiguously established, but see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26471/lower-number-vs-smaller-number; in computer programming, it's useful to have short terms for comparing magnitude vs. ordering.  While a paper which uses "larger" and "smaller" in reference to magnitude might do well to include a footnote at the first such usage explicitly defining such usage, being able to say e.g. "smaller" rather than "closer to zero" can make the text less cluttered and easy to read.

Comment: @supercat you don't need to redefine existing terms we have the absolute value for that

Comment: @JamesRyan: No, but when discussing things like floating-point addition algorithms, it's easier to discuss things in terms of the "larger" and "smaller" operand, than in terms of "the operand with the larger magnitude" and "the operand with the smaller magnitude".

Comment: @supercat:    I think it is entirely normal to consider -2 lower than -1, but -1 smaller than -2.   The very notion of size (smallness and largeness) relates to magnitude not ordering.

Comment: @ThePopMachine that entirely depends on the context.  A negative temperature in celsius for example does not have a larger magnitude.  The less than symbol (<) makes no sense if you start talking about a 'larger' number being less than a 'smaller' number just because it is negative.  The idea that magnitude and ordering are the default use of negative numbers is simply wrong for the vast majority of cases. We have notation to say when we are talking about a negative number's magnitude.  Just because YOU have got used to misusing terminology does not make it correct usage.

Comment: @JamesRyan:   I'm not going to engage in the bickering.   You yourself said it depends on context.   I merlye said it is normal for bare numbers like -1 and -2.   If you bring in your own context, then of course of you can find an exception.    But temperature scales are actually a rare exception because their zeroes don't map to an meaningful notion of zero for historical reasons.   This is a bad example.    Can you even think of another?    Absolute magnitude of stars comes to mind.    These are basically both obscure historical accidents where the zero was set before proper understanding.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I can think of many, it applies in just about any practical use of numbers other than counting because of the imprecision of what zero means when we define it.  But the main point is that in maths there is no such distinction between lower and smaller.  This is no need to bicker it is not opinion based, I am correcting you with a fact.

Comment: @JamesRyan:    Sorry you are so totally wrong and you keep trying to couch your wrongness in my misunderstanding.    You're the one declaring a "fact".   "Smaller" is an English word and so is "lower".   There is no mathematical definition for the word smaller which give you the right to claim some imagined "fact".   In math, the symbol '<' has a well defined meaning depending on the number set being used.    The terms "smaller" and "lower" don't mean anything mathematically rigorous without a mathematically rigorous definition in the paper (e.g.) to which they are being applied.

Comment: related comment [from question I asked some time ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843835/if-a-b-then-b-a-not-always-true-definition-of) `...and that's why formal language was invented. So everything means exactly what you said, nothing is "open to interpretation". I mean, He was right to go left, and right when he left, he went right.`

Comment: That a larger negative temperature in Celsius doesn't have a larger magnitude doesn't mean the terms "smaller" and "larger" have different meanings from their usage elsewhere; rather it simply means that have *no* useful meaning when applied to temperature.  The fact that -40C would not usually be described as a "larger" temperature than -1C doesn't mean it's a "smaller" temperature--it's just "lower".

Comment: @Mew both of your examples are flawed. Velocity has a direction, the negative value implies that but the speed component of a velocity is absolute and never negative. Displacement *from the origin* can't have a negative value and be an absolute value, you are trying to use it as both when it can only be one or the other.

Comment: @JamesRyan, displacement from the origin can indeed have an negative value because displacement is a vector.  So if you define one direction as positive and the other as negative, the sign in front of displacement will depend on which direction the displacement is in.  But you still didn't answer my question, what velocity is smaller, -300,000,000m/s or -1m/s?  It is just a question I pose and a question can't be incorrect.

Comment: @mew and the **magnitude** of the vector is 20m NOT -20m!

Comment: @mew -5. The displacement of -20 has a larger magnitude. Understand the key difference? Bringing us back round to the original point, the origin is arbitrary.

Answer (score 7):

Omega.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal), omega is

> the smallest ordinal [number] greater than every natural number.

Note that omega is an [transfinite number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number).

Answer (score 6):

First question

> It depends on the language :P. For example, "centomila" is Italian form of "a hundred thousand") :D

Answer (score 5):

In hexadecimal

> FEDCBA0 (read zero as 'Oh')

Which would be 267242400

In dozenal ( http://www.dozenalsociety.org.uk/roses/devlieger.html )

> <strike>forsen triliad</strike>

<strike>Which is 4.279728215×10¹⁴
Doh! Just noticed that i used 'r' twice. So the answer is</strike>

> <strike>twosen triliad</strike>

<strike>And the value is 1/2 of the prev one.</strike>

And i have just noticed the Bonus 2 for using a plus, so here it is:

> 8+ (Eight plus) This is regex, no less than one eight.

Comment: This demonstrates a double - i, and a missing double - l in trilliad. Since I don't know the language, I looked up the accepted spellings.

Comment: Double doh! i guess.

Comment: I don't know that it's fair to call a value hex without a prefix or suffix, since otherwise one could just as well declare a number to be base 36.  If one is using an old typewriter, though, one might argue for OxFEDCBAl, or lFEDCBAOh, depending upon what one is willing to accept as notation.

Comment: @supercat In that case (for the reason of fairness) we need to add "base ten" or similar to other answers. I do see what you are saying, but it is a limit imposed by the programming languages, not by the mathematics of base 16.

Comment: Your dozenal still uses two i's

Comment: In fairness, the question does stipulate "in word form", which reasonably eliminates hex representations. Of course, you could exploit the double-entendre that "word" also refers to a 16-bit quantity, or four hex digits, hence "FEDC" would constitute a number "in word form".

Comment: What's with these loop holes -_-

Comment: @warspyking: "Five thousand" is the largest "non-loophole" number, which can be trivially deduced. If you ask a question with a trivial answer, people tend to get creative. ;)

Comment: @COTO Actually i can make an argument that even "five thousand" is a "loophole" number since it uses space, which is not a letter. Basically some people read the question and think "these extra rules are implied" and some say to themselves "i wonder what rules were assumed by the author, that i don't have to assume".